# Do mods or console use disable achievements for Fallout:New Vegas?

Tags: pc, achievements, steam, fallout-new-vegas

I've heard mixed information on this and I'd like to get a straight answer, for two reasons:

1. The widely reported Quicksave/Autosave bug is annoying and, quite frankly, has terrified me into completely abandoning both features. However, manually saving is, to say the least, extremely cumbersome. In FO3, I used the console 'SAVE' command to create named save files without any menu navigation, and it was awesome. I've been afraid to do so in *New Vegas* however, for fear that, as reported, it will disable achievements on my save file.
2. Similarly, now that the game has been out for a few days, Mods are beginning to appear, and a few of them look like big QoL improvements. Most notably, stuff like [the return of DarnUI](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1126008-wipz-darnified-ui-fonv/), to fix the horridly large print menus, and [Imma Sightin Mah Lazor](http://www.newvegasnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=34847), to add Iron Sights to the Laser Pistol. But again, not worth it on my first playthrough if they ruin my hard earned Nerd Points on Steam.

Since I've heard conflicting information on this, I'd love to get a definitive answer, but sadly, having earned the 'low hanging fruit' achievements you can get without a whole fresh playthrough or a lot of grinding with a specific weapon type, I have no easy way to test this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best source I have for this is the [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_achievements_and_trophies). They say:

> Please note that cheating, on the PC version at least, appears to disable achievements for that play. If you are cheating (or using console commands to get around bugs) , you won't get any achievements unless you save, quit, reload, and redo the achievement.

Unfortunately I can't test this myself, but this seems to stem from experimentation.

Oh, seeing as you mentioned it: I'm fairly sure using cheats will not remove any achievements you've earned before. That's just the way Steam works.

**Update:** Using mods does not affect achievements at all. Only console commands are construed as cheating.

Comment: Does this effect everything? When I got ED-E as my first companion I didn't get the steam achivement, nor when I got Burke, did I get the second one