# Fixing unearned achievements in Fallout New Vegas

Tags: steam, pc, achievements, fallout-new-vegas

I completed Old World Blues and managed to get my brain back. Yet, I received neither `Make up your Mind` or `Outsmarted` on my Steam achievements. I did not [use console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9743/11391) (on purpose or by accident) to mess with the game on that session. I did go back and redo the quest(s) and still did not get the achievements. Is there some way to force New Vegas to tell Steam I got them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just replaying the last part again and Fallout decided to not be buggy and gave me the achievements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/) to give yourselves the achievements. You can also try looking for a mod that unlocks achievements.